# How to comb two tensors together in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

What is the canonical / recommended way of combing two tensors together? By combing I mean this for example, if we have let's say two 2D-tensors, I want the corresponding parts along dim=1 to be next to each other:

[image: combing example]

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
import torch

a = torch.tensor([[1, 2],[3, 4]])
b = 10 * a
c = torch.zeros((a.shape[0], 2*a.shape[1]), dtype=a.dtype)
c[:, 0::2] = a
c[:, 1::2] = b
print("a:\n", a)
print("b:\n", b)
print("c:\n", c)
```

The result is:

```
a:
 tensor([[1, 2],
        [3, 4]])
b:
 tensor([[10, 20],
        [30, 40]])
c:
 tensor([[ 1, 10,  2, 20],
        [ 3, 30,  4, 40]])
```